# How can I pass the string that reveals the qrcode to a variable in ReactNative?

Tags: javascript, variables, react-native, parameter-passing, barcode-scanner

I have followed many guides on interner but I have never managed to make it work. This class opens the qrcode scanner and should insert the string inside the 'qrcode' variable, but I just can not.
This is my class:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, AppRegistry, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Constants, BarCodeScanner, Permissions } from 'expo';


class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
render() {
  return (
    <Text style={styles.input}>
      1) QRCode: 
      <Text style={styles.inputPos}> {qrcode} </Text>
    </Text>

    <TouchableOpacity
     style={styles.button}
     onPress={() => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
    }>
     <Text> SCAN </Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>

);
}
}


class ScanQRCode extends React.Component {
  state = {
   hasCameraPermission: null
  };

componentDidMount() {
  this._requestCameraPermission();
 }

 _requestCameraPermission = async () => {
  const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
this.setState({
  hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted',
   });
 };

 _handleBarCodeRead = data => {

Alert.alert(
  'Scan successful!',
  JSON.stringify(data)
);
qrcode = data;    
};

   render() {
  return (
  <View style={styles.container2}>
    {this.state.hasCameraPermission === null ?
      <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text> :
      this.state.hasCameraPermission === false ?
        <Text>Camera permission is not granted</Text> :
        <BarCodeScanner
          onBarCodeRead={this._handleBarCodeRead}
          style={{ height: 200, width: 200 }}
        />
    }
  </View>
 );
 }
 }
```

I want the variable 'data' scanned by the qrcode to enter the variable 'qrcode' and display it next to it

Comment: I dont see any place defining the `qrcode` variable in your `HomeScreen`.